# Weibull distribution

Tags: python, database, statistics, approximation, weibull

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aTrd.png)  : here is my data , I'm trying to find the shape and scale parameters that fit with this set using python . any ideas?   [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgg2K.png)

I used the the maximum likelihood estimation method and I found a shape parameter 1.8 and scale parameter  44 .However , when I plot the distribution , it doesn't fit with the histogram .

Thank you